# Jabber bot - how to get presence updates?

Tags: python, linux, xmpp, openfire

I'm using the following code to connect to xmpp server (python + xmppy):

```
  c = xmpp.Client("localhost", debug=[])
  c.connect(("127.0.0.1", 5222))
  c.auth("test","test")
  c.sendInitPresence()
  c.send(xmpp.Presence(to="admin@localhost", typ='subscribe'))
  time.sleep(1000)
```

This works just fine, the admin user get's the presence update and in contacts the "test" user is shown as online. The problem occurs if I press ctrl+c on this script (when it's sleeping at the end), so it's terminated. The problem is that the admin user doesn't get a presence update from that script.

I should also mention that the admin user accepts subscription requests automatically.

My question is: how can the admin user detect that the test user went offline. And changing the above script is not an option, since anybody can write this and pose a program on my xmpp server.

Any ideas why the admin doesn't receive presence update or how to detect that the user 'test' went offline are welcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Detecting that an endpoint has gone offline without a specific presence update is usually handled by the server, by eg. detecting that the socket that the endpoint is communicating on has been closed.

If you only have control over client code, you could send occasional [presence probes](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6121#section-4.3) from the admin client to all its subscribed endpoints.

Comment: Hi. I have control over the XMPP server, which is openfire and it doesn't send present updates if the above script is used. And it detects that the user has gone offline, because if I list all users the 'test' user is marked as offline. There's just no presence update. I guess that 'admin' user should receive presence update, since the above script adds it in the 'test' roster - and since admin automatically accepts subscription. So I don't know what's going on that 'admin' doesn't get the offline presence update, but openfire detects that the user 'test' has gone offline.

Comment: Then it sounds like it may be an Openfire bug. The XMPP specification says that the server must generate an unavailable presence if the client gets disconnected: http://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc6121.html#presence-unavailable-outbound